# Enclose JSON elements in individual lists

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

My incoming JSON data from the server looks like this:

```
["ask_buyer_question_body-en",
 "ask_buyer_question_subject-en",
 "user_verification_subject-en"]
```

The client-side control expects it to look like this:

```
[["One"], ["Two"], ["Three"]]
```

Is there a programmatic way to change the original array? I can use string manipulation if necessary but would rather avoid it.

Comment: Why don't you change your client-side logic to accept this format from the server?

Answer (score 5):

Just `map` it:

```
var newArray = serverArray.map(function (val) { return [val]; });
```

If you have to support IE < 9, either use jQuery's [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), or use [MDN's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).